# Swift instr or strpos Equivalent

Tags: swift, strpos

I've searched and searched but can't see to find what the instr or strpos equivalent in Swift is.  Just need to see if a string contains a string.  How can I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rangOfString()`:

```
if string.rangeOfString("mySubstring") != nil
{
    println("string contains substring")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful extension of String in **Swift**. Both functions work like the well known PHP functions. Just paste this code in any .swift file of your project:

```
import Foundation
extension String {
    func strpos(needle:String)->Int{
        //Returns the index of the first occurrence of a substring in a string, or -1 if absent
        if let range = self.rangeOfString(needle) {
            return startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex)
        } else {
            return -1
        }

    }
    func instr(needle:String)->Bool{
        return self.containsString(needle)
    }
}
```

Usage, anywhere else in your projet

```
let myString = "Hello, world"
print(myString.strpos("world")) //->prints "7"
print(myString.strpos("Dolly")) //->prints "-1"
print(myString.strpos(",")) //->prints "5"
```